# c# explode tuple into dictionary entry

Tags: c#

Hi I have a function that returns a tuple of 2 values and I want to put them into a one-line add as seen below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
test.Add(intoDict());

private (string, string) intoDict()
{
    return ("Key","Value");
}
```

I need this to be a one-line operation.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What problems are you encountering with your implementation.

Comment: I tried the code above and that doesn't work as it is seen as one value, instead of 2, other than this I have no idea how to tackle it without creating more unnecessary code. I need to call this function many time so I want to keep it clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for whatever reason it absolutely has to be a oneliner, you can create an extension method to handle the tuple value:

```cs
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, ValueTuple<TKey, TValue> tuple)
        {
            dic[tuple.Item1] = tuple.Item2;
        }
    }
```

which can then be called like this:

```cs
static (string, string) intoDict()
{
    return ("Key", "Value");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add(intoDict()); //added here
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the **key** and **value** separately like below in `Add` method as it expects two parmeters, first key and second value :

```
var tupleResult = intoDict();
test.Add(tupleResult.Item1, tupleResult.Item2);
```

Comment: This way works indeed, but that is not a oneliner and would create more code than I have already... So I am trying to look for a clean way to do this.

Comment: @RobinDeWolf You may be using a wrong definition of "clean".

Comment: It already doesn't look clean to have a method like `intoDict` in the first place which returns a single static tuple which you don't need anyway. Why you don''t provide a method that builds the dictionary?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ofcourse there are multiple approaches to get this done and jack posted already via extension method if we really want it one liner

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an [extension method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

```cs
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T, U>(this IDictionary<T, U> Dictionary, (T, U) tuple)
    {
        Dictionary.TryAdd(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    }
}
```

This extension method provides an `.Add()` to any `IDictionary`.

To use this simply do:

```cs
(string,string) myTuple = ( "Key", "Value");

dictionary.Add(myTuple);
```